# Durrett Thm 3.2.2

Tags: probability-theory

I'm currently going over this theorem in Durrett's probability book. I don't get why the existence of a rational number in each of $(a_x, b_x)$ gives us that $\Omega - \Omega_0$ is countable. Any ideas? 
[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand his argument, but one way to see that his conclusion holds is the following: $F$ is monotone and bounded and thus the set of all points where it jumps $\Omega\setminus \Omega_0$ is countable.

Comment: The remark shows that $(a_x,b_x)$ is nonempty for at most countably many $x$. To belabor the obvious, send every $x$ in $\Omega_0\setminus\Omega$ to any rational number $q(x)$ in $(a_x,b_x)$, then the map $q:\Omega_0\setminus\Omega\to\mathbb Q$ is injective (do you see why?) hence $\Omega_0\setminus\Omega$ is at most countable (in the sense of, it is countable or finite or empty).

Comment: @Did yes, since $(a_x, b_x)$ are disjoint. Thanks!